# Awesomplete set label text field and hidden field value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using Awesomplete for easy text field autocomplete. I have an array with label and value, and when something is selected I wan't it to compleate the text and ad the value (in this case ID) into a hidden field.

[docs](https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/)

Anyone know how to do this?

Code example:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Titel" required />
<input type="hidden" id="id" name="id">
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$titles = array();
    foreach ($data as $title){
            $titles[] = array(
                "label" =>  $title->title,
                "value" => $title->id,
            );

    }
?>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //array with all titles and id from a php array
    var jArray = <?php echo json_encode($titles); ?>;

    var input = document.getElementById("title");

    var input2 = document.getElementById("id");

    new Awesomplete(input, {
        list: jArray
    });



</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the awesomplete-selectcomplete event to set the val of your hidden input by doing this

```
            window.addEventListener("awesomplete-selectcomplete", function(e){
                input2.value = e.text.value;
            }, false);
```

Go to https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/#events to know more about events, but to quote it, "*Callback will be passed an object with a text property containing the selected suggestion.*"

Answer (score 2):

Do this :

```html
<input id="myinput-hidden" name="lang" type="hidden" />
<input id="myinput" />
```

```js
var hidden = $("#myinput-hidden");

new Awesomplete("#myinput", {
    list: [["Ada", 1], ["Java", 2], ["JavaScript", 3], ["Brainfuck", 4], ["LOLCODE", 5], ["Node.js", 6], ["Ruby on Rails", 7]],

    // the only function you need to override:
    replace: function(suggestion) {
        this.input.value = suggestion.label; // default replace() inserts suggestion.value to input
        hidden.value = suggestion.value;
    }
});
```